# Spring CachingConnectionFactory limiting channels & causing Thread Blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-rabbit

I have a simple message publisher publishing to rabbitmq (local) at very high rate.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, factory);

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    int finalI = i;
    threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            messagePublisher.publishMessage("testExchange", "testRoutingKey1", message + String.valueOf(finalI));
        }
    });
}
```

Here messagePublisher is an instance of the following class

```
public class ChannelCachedMessagePublisher {

    private static CachingConnectionFactory CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    private static RabbitTemplate RABBIT_TEMPLATE;

    private void init() {
        if (!INITIALIZED) {
            synchronized (ConnectionCachedMessagePublisher.class) {
                CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY.setCacheMode(CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode.CHANNEL);
                CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY.setChannelCacheSize(100);
                CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY.setVirtualHost("testVHost");
                CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY.setConnectionNameStrategy(CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY -> "arpit-cached-connection");
                CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY.setPublisherConfirms(false);
                RABBIT_TEMPLATE = new RabbitTemplate(CACHING_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            }
            INITIALIZED = true;
        }
    }

    public void publishMessage(String exchange, String routingKey, String message) {

        RABBIT_TEMPLATE.convertAndSend(exchange, routingKey, message, new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                MessageProperties properties = message.getMessageProperties();
                properties.setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                return new org.springframework.amqp.core.Message(message.getBody(),properties);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Upon execution of this code, the 5 threads creates only 5 channels over a single connection.

**EDIT 1**
1). Why is connection factory not providing more than 5 threads here and associating threads per thread?
This part is clear now as connection factory can not provide more channels (or connections) then the number of running threads itself.

Next, immediately all the threads starts getting blocked over the monitor object in SocketFrameHandler.

> "arpit-rmq-5" #1019 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fb90c5b8800
>   nid=0x83303 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700047bca000]
>   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
>           at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.writeFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:170)

[Here's a view of the threads post execution exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFgFP.png)

2). Why exactly are these threads getting blocked and what can be the workarounds to resolve the same?

NOTE: This leads to moving my rabbit connection in flow control state, with which I am fine. My main concern is the thread blocking in JVM.

Comment: Your question is not clear - you are only using 5 threads `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, factory);` Why do you expect the factory to create more threads?

Comment: @GaryRussell Sorry if it's naive, but I am trying to understand the same. If the connection factory is always returning set of channels equal to the number of running threads, then why are these threads trying to access each other's channels and run into **BLOCKED** state [(thread state image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFgFP.png). Shouldn't these threads be executing their task, returning the channel to the cache and let the channel be reused by some other thread if required?

Comment: That's exactly what happens; after each publish, the channel is returned to the cache and used by the next request. Since you are publishing at a high rate, you are probably just blocking because of network bandwidth or broker issues. Since you are sharing a single connection, each write has to be discrete. Consider using `cacheMode` `CONNECTION` to use a connection for each publisher.

Comment: Or can this be because in a highly concurrent environment, multiple threads are getting the same **free** _(at that point in time)_ channel from the connection factory? As write over socket via this connection is synchronised, certain threads are getting blocked. Sample thread dump (omitted in between)

`com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.writeFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:170)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955)`

Comment: No; it is not possible for multiple threads to get the same channel concurrently; they do, however, share a connection. Channels are multiplexed over the connection they were created on; to avoid mixed packets, the `SocketFramewriter` synchronizes on the socket's `OutputStream`. Only one channel can write to the socket at a time. As I said, you might get better performance with `cacheMode` `CONNECTION`, but probably not if the limiting factor is your network.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot for this clarification @GaryRussell. This resolves my query. Yeah, I tried with `cacheMode` `CONNECTION`. That does give me better performance up till a limit, but then network becomes bottleneck.